# OpenVPN отключается, если больше 1 одновременного соединения

Tags: openvpn

У меня есть рабочий OpenVPN на Ubuntu 16.0, он работает хорошо. Но есть проблема, если кто-то уже подключен к впн и я подключаюсь, то соединение у первого подключившегося пропадает. То есть впн не разрешает больше одного одновременного подключения. В чем б могут быть проблемы?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: ключ не один у клиента? В общем конфигурации у клиентов нужно посмотреть

Comment: Ключи у клиентов разные?

Comment: Ключи одинаковы. Для каждого нужны отдельные ключи и сертификаты?

Comment: вообще то я для каждого клиента делаю свой ключ. Считал, что это очевидно. И нет проблем с подсоединениями.